# Blur event stops click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example code: http://jsfiddle.net/slolife/PnmxM/

I am asking this even though there are a number of similar questions, but I feel that they are not the same.

I have an textbox that when it is blurred, should do something.

I also have a link, that is always visible (that appears to be how the other questions differ) and when clicked, should do something.

My blur handler fires, but the click handler does not.

Is there a proper way to deal with this?

**Update**

Many people pointed out that the alerts were causing my problem.  Thank you.  In my real code, I do not have alerts, but instead remove the textbox from the DOM.

So I have updated the fiddle to better reflect that with console.log calls instead of alert() calls.  Any additional help is appreciated.

Comment: they both fire fine for me, what browser are u using?

Comment: it's not working for me in Chrome?

Comment: both events show the appropriate alert in the order they are fired

Comment: I am using Chrome Beta and FF 7.0.1.  So you click in the textbox and then click the "add" link and there is a "blur" alert and then an "add" alert?  Strange.  That does not happen for me. If my focus is in the textbox and I attempt to click the add link, I only get the blur alert.

Comment: alert() was my attempt to make a simple example, but did not match my code exactly.  Please see my updated fiddle.

Comment: I want to give credit where credit is due, so should I award the answer to @icyrock.com and create an new question with my new fiddle?

Comment: blur will works before the click event normally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because of the first `alert` breaking the second `alert` because it's modal. See this:

- http://jsfiddle.net/PnmxM/4/

Here, I'm appending the message to `msgs` div and it works as expected.

For your updated jsFiddle, here's an (updated-updated?) working one:

- http://jsfiddle.net/PnmxM/10/

You are removing the input box in your `onBlur` and, as a consequence of that, moving the `Add item` vertically, thus the click doesn't happen on `Add item` anymore (as your mouse pointer did not move in the meantime), but on some other element (in this case, a jsFiddle example container). Moving `Add item` above the disappearing `input` element solves the "click me if you can" issue.

Comment: Ah, got lucky this time... ;)

Comment: alert() was my attempt to make a simple example, but did not match my code exactly.  Please see my updated fiddle.

Comment: Similar thing - see for a working thing here: http://jsfiddle.net/PnmxM/10/. Just moved `Add item` above the box. The thing is the events are processed in order. When you click somewhere, `onBlur` is executed before any `onClick`s are processed. However, your `onBlur` removes the input box and thus moves the `Add item` link. The click doesn't happen on `Add item` anymore - it happens on some other element (the jsFiddle container in this case), so there's no `add` in your Firebug console...

Comment: I'd give you extra points for sticking with it after the edit.  Thank you.

Comment: @icyrock.com please see my problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896084/jquery-ajax-on-focusout-on-submit-requires-2-clicks i have asked many people to solve but no one could give a solution

Answer (score 3):

The click event is not firing because that only happens when you release the mouse button.  That isn't happening because there is a modal dialog window visible (the alert window).  If you change the alerts to `console.log` instead then it works perfectly...

http://jsfiddle.net/PnmxM/7/

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using an `alert` you are interrupting the execution, which causes a problem for me in Firefox - but if you switch to `console.log` and make sure you have a console (like Firebug) open, you can see both events fire.

```
function onBlur() {
    console.log('blur');
}

function addItem() {
    console.log('add');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#items').delegate('input','blur', onBlur);
    $('#addItem').click(addItem);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, another way to fix this if you can't rearrange your UI is to simply bind to the `mousedown` event instead of `click`.  I've added my [own modification](http://jsfiddle.net/PnmxM/36/) of the console.log() jsFiddle to demonstrate.

I ran into this issue with a menu that showed when the user focuses on a text box, and hides when they blur.  Clicks in the menu weren't firing in Chrome, because the blur hid the menu on mousedown, so when the mouse came back up the pointer wasn't in the menu any more (because it had disappeared), since that handler then got called before blur hid the menu, and my click events hit their targets.

Answer (score 0):

Just try after update the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/slolife/PnmxM/.

Update the onBlur function to this.

Blur and click will works.

```
 function onBlur() {
        console.log('blur');
        $('#item').val("test");
    }
```

Current issue is : the click is not triggering because the ui position of "Add item" is changing (because the textfield disappears).